# How can i persisting dropdown selection in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a dropdown list for search. How can i create a dropdown with four values in mvc. when i select a value from dropdown and click on search button, the corresponding fields will be displayed, but the selection will be changed to default value.

For example,dropdown has 4 values. Default value will be select and other values are Red, Geen, Blue and Orange. When i select Blue, and click search button, all the fields related to blue will displayed, but the selection is missing. Its go back to select.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this script:    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++) {
                            if (s.options[i].text == v) {
                                s.options[i].selected = true;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    var name = '@ViewData["ColorName"]';
                   setSelectedIndex(document.getElementById('IDofDropDown'), '' + name + '');
    });
```

Pass View data value from Controller